# jQuery html method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating an upvote/downvote functionality on an app I am building. When a user hits the upvote or downvote button, an ajax request is submitted to a controller which updates a vote count in the database and then runs a javascript file that uses jquery to update the displayed votes count and disable the button pressed. Here is the jquery to update the display:

```
$('#post-action-<%= "#{@post.id}" %>').html("
                <i class=\"icon-arrow-up arrow-voted\"></i>
                <p class=\"votes_difference\" ><%= (post.upvotes - post.downvotes) %></p>
            <%= link_to raw(\"<i class=\"icon-arrow-down\"></i>\"), post_downvote_path(post.id), method: :put, remote: true %>
                <p class=\"votes_sum\" ><%= (post.upvotes + post.downvotes) %> votes</p>
");
```

Everything works, except for updating the vote display and changing the upvote button (in other words, the above code is not being run. The database is updated, so I know the conroller is run successfully.). I also know that the problem is with the jquery above becuase it was working when I was rendering a much less html. Here is the simplier code that I previously had working:

```
$('#post-action-<%= "#{@post.id}" %>').html("<%= @post.upvotes - @post.downvotes %>")
```

I am postive that I am grabbing the correct element. The html element content I am replacing is:

```
<div class="post_actions" id="post-action-<%= "#{post.id}" %>" >

...some embedded ruby and other html

</div>
```

I assuming there is some jquery syntax error, but I simply cannot find it. I am at my wits end here. Any and all input on this matter would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

As referenced in the comments of Trip's answer, I was able to print foobar by changing this:

```
$('#post-action-<%= "#{ @post.id }" %>').html("fooooooobar!")
```

to this:

```
$('#post-action-<%= @post.id %>').html("fooooooobar!")
```

However, when I then replace foobar with the more complex code:

```
$('#post-action-<%= @post.id %>').html("

                <i class='icon-arrow-up arrow-voted'></i>
                <p class='votes_difference' >
                  <%= (@post.upvotes - @post.downvotes) %>
                </p>
            <%= link_to raw('<i class=\"icon-arrow-down\"></i>'), post_downvote_path(@post.id), method: :put, remote: true %>
                <p class='votes_sum' ><%= (@post.upvotes + @post.downvotes) %> votes</p>

");
```

The problem returns. The user display does not update. However, this time around, the console has a jquery error:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/course/1/upvote_post 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8241
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js:8241
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7720
$.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js:99
$.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js:158
(anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js:309
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3333
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

**EDIT 2**

After playing around with the jquery code, I have noticed a couple of things. Firstly, I have to minify the code. If I do not, the jQuery does not fire. For example, I should do this:

```
$('#post-action-<%= "#{ @post.id }" %>').html("fooooooobar!")
```

instead of this:

```
$('#post-action-<%= "#{ @post.id }" %>').html("
              fooooooobar!
")
```

Secondly, after entering each line back into the html method, I have identified the line that causes a problem. This line:

```
<%= link_to raw(\"<i class=\"icon-arrow-down\"></i>\"), post_downvote_path(post.id), method: :put, remote: true %>
```

Causes the jquery to fail. I tried the line without the 'raw':

```
 <%= link_to "<i class='icon-arrow-down'></i>", post_downvote_path(post.id), method: :put, remote: true %>
```

But still nothing.

**SOLUTION - AH YEA**

In order to get the link line to work, I had to escape it like so:

```
<%= escape_javascript(link_to raw("<i class='icon-arrow-down'></i>"), post_downvote_path(@post.id), method: :put, remote: true) %>
```

Finally! Free at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's this line :

```
<%= link_to raw(\"<i class=\"icon-arrow-down\"></i>\"),
```

So do this :

```
$('#post-action-<%= "#{@post.id}" %>').html("
                <i class='icon-arrow-up arrow-voted'></i>
                <p class='votes_difference' >
                  <%= (post.upvotes - post.downvotes) %>
                </p>
            <%= link_to raw('<i class=\"icon-arrow-down\"></i>'), post_downvote_path(post.id), method: :put, remote: true %>
                <p class='votes_sum' ><%= (post.upvotes + post.downvotes) %> votes</p>
");
```

**Update**

The reason this line fails :

```
\"<i class=\"icon-arrow-down\"></i>\"),
```

Is because you are using `/"` to enclose another `/"` so the app is thinking that there are two parts here :

```
\"<i class=\"
```

and

```
\"></i>\"
```

You need to differentiate them. You are already using `"` for your `html()` method so use `'`

So it would look like this :

```
'<i class=\"icon-arrow-down\"></i>'),
```

Secondly, escape_javascript the link:

```
<%= escape_javascript(link_to raw("<i class='icon-arrow-down'></i>"), post_downvote_path(@post.id), method: :put, remote: true) %>
```

Comment: Hmm.. have you tried removing it line by line until you have a working `html()` jquery Method? Start with this : `$('#post-action-<%= "#{@post.id}" %>').html("fooooooobar!")`

Comment: Also are any errors popping up in your console.. are we sure this is exclusively a jQuery error? I'm still pretty sure its that line i mentioned above ;)

Comment: Its strange. I can't even get the foobar line to work now: $('#post-action-<%= "#{ @post.id }" %>').html("fooooooobar!");   There are no errors in the console. I have to believe its a jquery error though b/c the controller is being run successfully and the 'id' is named correctly, and the like.

Comment: Interesting. And does your original "working" answer still work? Can you post your controller code? I'm curious if its responding appropriately with the right infos..

Comment: ok, I have an update, but im going to put it in an edit so it is cleaner.

Comment: a 500 means the wrong infos is probably getting sent to your controller. did you try yet throwing a `debugger` in your `update` action?

Comment: Ok, I played around with it some more and found out some more info. I put the specifics in 'EDIT 2.' Your original instincts were right, however, as the line causing the problem is the link.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. After making sure your edits were included within the 'link_to', I had to escape the link with 'escape_javascript'. Thanks for all your help man :)

Comment: Awesome! Sorry I couldn't help more ;D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed @post inside the html and just have it as post. Try this.

By the way, you should use firebug or chrome inspect element to figure any script errors. They even point out the ajax related script errors when they happen.

> $('#post-action-<%= "#{@post.id}" %>').html("
>                   
>                   <%= (@post.upvotes - @post.downvotes) %>
>
> <%= link_to raw(\"\"), post_downvote_path(@post.id), method: :put, remote: true %>
>                   <%= (@post.upvotes + @post.downvotes) %> votes ");